# How to pass the UI Table row data dynamically to a Simpleform in SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

In form view, I tried aggregation binding, which didn't happen. My table view looks like this :

```
<mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="com.Lata12NavUI1.controller.Table"
    xmlns:t="sap.ui.table" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <Page title="UI Table">
        <content>
            <t:Table id="table" rows="{StaticModel>/results}" rowActionCount="2" selectionMode="MultiToggle" visibleRowCount="2" paste="onPaste"
                ariaLabelledBy="title">
                <t:columns type="Navigation">
                    <t:Column width="11rem">
                        <Label text="Object no"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Text text="{StaticModel>Objnr}" wrapping="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="11rem">
                        <Label text="Personal no"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Text text="{StaticModel>Pernr}" wrapping="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="11rem">
                        <Label text="First Name"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Text text="{StaticModel>Fname}" wrapping="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                    <t:Column width="11rem">
                        <Label text="Last Name"/>
                        <t:template>
                            <Text text="{StaticModel>Lname}" wrapping="false"/>
                        </t:template>
                    </t:Column>
                </t:columns>
                <t:rowActionTemplate>
                    <t:RowAction>
                        <t:RowActionItem type="Navigation" press="onPress" icon="sap-icon://feeder-arrow" visible="true"></t:RowActionItem>
                    </t:RowAction>
                </t:rowActionTemplate>
            </t:Table>
        </content>
    </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

Form view :

```
<mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="com.Lata12NavUI1.controller.Form"
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <Page id="Page" showNavButton="true" navButtonPress="onNavBack" title="Simple Form">
        <l:Grid class="sapUiSmallMargin">
            <f:SimpleForm id="SimpleFormToolbar" editable="true" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout" labelSpanXL="4" labelSpanL="3" labelSpanM="4"
                labelSpanS="12" adjustLabelSpan="false" emptySpanXL="0" emptySpanL="4" emptySpanM="0" emptySpanS="0" columnsXL="2" columnsL="1" columnsM="1"
                singleContainerFullSize="false" ariaLabelledBy="Title1">
                <f:content>
                    
                    <Label text="Object no."/>
                    <Input value="{StaticModel>Objnr}" id="Objnr"/>
                    <Label text="Personal no."/>
                    <Input value="{StaticModel>Pernr}" id="Pennr"/>
                    <Label text="First name"/>
                    <Input value="{StaticModel>Fname}" id="Fname"/>
                    <Label text="Last name"/>
                    <Input value="{StaticModel>Lname}" id="Lname"></Input>
                    <!--<core:Title text="Office" />-->
                    <Label text="Sex"/>
                    <Select id="sex" selectedKey="{Select}">
                        <items>
                            <core:Item text="Select" key="Select"/>
                            <core:Item text="Male" key="Male"/>
                            <core:Item text="Female" key="Female"/>
                        </items>
                    </Select>
                    <Label text="Date"/>
                    <DatePicker id="DP1"/>
                    <Toolbar>
                        <Button id="btn" type="Emphasized" text="Submit" press="onSubmit"></Button>
                        <Button type="Reject" text="Reset" press="onPress"></Button>
                    </Toolbar>
                </f:content>
            </f:SimpleForm>
        </l:Grid>
    </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

So in Form controller I binded element using :

```
this.getView().bindElement("StaticModel>/results/0");
```

in OnInit function. But onClick of any row, I am getting the same data in form irrespective of row. Please help me to bind the row data in form dynamically.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`onInit` and `onAfterRendering` are only called once. If you bind your page in `onInit` the binding will never be changed after first page visit.

Define your [routes](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.36.6/docs/guide/e5200ee755f344c8aef8efcbab3308fb.html) in **manifest.json**

```
"targets": {
  "Form": {
    "viewName": "Form"
  },
  "Table": {
    "viewName": "Table"
  }
],
"routes": [{
  "pattern": "Form/{path}",
  "name": "Form"
},{
  "pattern": "Table",
  "name": "Table"
}]
```

**Table controller**

```
onPress: function(oEvent){
  var oItem = oEvent.getSource();
  var sPath = oItem.getBindingContext("StaticModel").getPath(); //get object path from selected row
  var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);

  oRouter.navTo("Form", { //navigate to form and hand over the object path
    path: sPath
  });
}
```

**Form controller**

```
onInit: function(){
  var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
  oRouter.getRoute("Form").attachPatternMatched(this._onRouteMatched, this); //Every time your form view is displayed call _onRouteMatched method
},

_onRouteMatched: function(oEvent) {
  var sPath = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").path; //get path from arguments
  this.getView().bindElement("StaticModel>" + sPath); //Bind path to view
}
```

Comment: If I changed as above, I am getting the error as "Invalid value "/results/0" for segment "{path}". Please help.

Comment: https://answers.sap.com/questions/12435641/routing-invalid-value--for-segment.html